# Como ignorar o último elemento em chamada recursiva

Tags: c

Estou implementando uma árvore em C, e um dos meus métodos imprime a minha árvore em pré-ordem, e separando os números com `-`.

Criei essa função:

```
void ImprimePreOrdem(TipoApontador arv){
    if(arv!=NULL){
        printf("%d-",arv->chave);
        ImprimePreOrdem(arv->esq);
        ImprimePreOrdem(arv->dir);
    }
}
```

Porém, por exemplo se minha árvore conter os números de 1 a 10, quando eu imprimo os elementos da árvore recursivamente, a aplicação bota o `-` no final, ficando a saída assim:

> 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-9-10-

Como eu faço pra excluir esse último `-` da minha saída?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem várias formas de implementar a lógica que pretende. A solução que lhe mostro passa por inverter um pouco a lógica, para que mostrar o primeiro elemento normalmente, e cada elemento da frente mostra primeiro o traço e depois o numero. Desta maneira sai sempre certo e não precisa de saber qual o ultimo elemento para "cancelar o ultimo traço".

Como sabe qual o primeiro elemento para imprimir diferente ?

Pois bem tem também várias alternativas, uma simples é passar o nível do elemento em que está a imprimir, sendo que a raiz é o nível `0`. No nível `0` imprime apenas o numero, e nos outros níveis imprime primeiro o traço para ligar com o anterior, e depois o numero.

Para manter a função que tem com o mesmo prototipo precisa de outra função auxiliar que inclua o nível e o vá aumentando em cada chamada.

Implementação da lógica sugerida:

```
void ImprimePreOrdemAux(TipoApontador arv, int nivel){
    if(arv != NULL){
        if (nivel != 0){ //so imprime o traço do anterior se não for o primeiro
            printf("-");
        }
        printf("%d",arv->chave);
        ImprimePreOrdemAux(arv->esq, nivel + 1);
        ImprimePreOrdemAux(arv->dir, nivel + 1);
    }
}

void ImprimePreOrdem(TipoApontador arv){
    ImprimePreOrdemAux(arv, 0); //chama a função auxiliar com nivel 0
}
```

Também pode implementar o mesmo sem uma função auxiliar e colocando o `nivel` como variável global, mas é certamente uma solução pior ainda que seja mais simples.

[Veja um exemplo desta implementação a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/MPAGgM)

Note também que esta solução irá funcionar para qualquer uma das três formas de percorrer a arvore, a *infix*, *prefix* ou *postfix*.